# How do I put text at the bottom of an image?

Tags: html, css

New to CSS. Is there any way I can put text (or a link) below an image?

For some reason the text goes to the bottom right of the image whenever I do:

```html
<a href="#"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></a>

<a href="#footer">Jump to Bottom</a>
```

Here's the whole code. It's a rendition freeCodeCamp's "Responsive Web Design" course with all the visual features combined into one file:

```html
<h2>CatPhotoApp</h2>
<main>
  <p>Click here to view more <a href="#">cat photos</a>.</p>

  <a href="#"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back."></a>

<a href="#footer">Jump to Bottom</a>

  <p>Kitty ipsum dolor sit amet, shed everywhere shed everywhere stretching attack your ankles chase the red dot, hairball run catnip eat the grass sniff. Purr jump eat the grass rip the couch scratched sunbathe, shed everywhere rip the couch sleep in the sink fluffy fur catnip scratched. Kitty ipsum dolor sit amet, shed everywhere shed everywhere stretching attack your ankles chase the red dot, hairball run catnip eat the grass sniff.</p>
  <p>Purr jump eat the grass rip the couch scratched sunbathe, shed everywhere rip the couch sleep in the sink fluffy fur catnip scratched. Kitty ipsum dolor sit amet, shed everywhere shed everywhere stretching attack your ankles chase the red dot, hairball run catnip eat the grass sniff. Purr jump eat the grass rip the couch scratched sunbathe, shed everywhere rip the couch sleep in the sink fluffy fur catnip scratched.</p>
  <p>Meowwww loved it, hated it, loved it, hated it yet spill litter box, scratch at owner, destroy all furniture, especially couch or lay on arms while you're using the keyboard. Missing until dinner time toy mouse squeak roll over. With tail in the air lounge in doorway. Man running from cops stops to pet cats, goes to jail.</p>
  <p>Intently stare at the same spot poop in the plant pot but kitten is playing with dead mouse. Get video posted to internet for chasing red dot leave fur on owners clothes meow to be let out and mesmerizing birds leave fur on owners clothes or favor packaging over toy so purr for no reason. Meow to be let out play time intently sniff hand run outside as soon as door open yet destroy couch.</p>

</main>

  <div>
    <p>Things cats love:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>cat nip</li>
      <li>laser pointers</li>
      <li>lasagna</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Top 3 things cats hate:</p>
    <ol>
      <li>flea treatment</li>
      <li>thunder</li>
      <li>other cats</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <form action="https://freecatphotoapp.com/submit-cat-photo">
    <label><input type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor" checked> Indoor</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor"> Outdoor</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality" checked> Loving</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality"> Lazy</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="personality"> Energetic</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="cat photo URL" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</main>

<footer id="footer">Copyright Cat Photo App</footer>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: Add a line break. `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

That's because both links are inline objects, you need to set both or first as block elements with 'display: block' or maybe put some `<br />` after the first one.

```
<a href="#" class="something">
<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back.">
</a>

<a href="#footer">Jump to Bottom</a>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
a.something {
  display: block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome in css ...

Here,  tag is inline element (normally inline element allow another inline element in the same line if any space remain after it's content)

so, you used two inline element (a & a). first  contains  after that there is space remaining in the same line. That's why second  tag sat after it.

So, if u convert any of one into block-level element (block level element stay alone in it's line - one line), you can divide them into two line

**Solution:**

> ```
> #footer {    
>     display: block; 
> }
> ```

or can do any/both of them () block